# Transferring to external URL's using SpUtility.Redirect method

Tags: sharepoint

Can someone please tell me how to transfer to another external page like  http://google.com using sputility.redirect method .I can transfer to pages withing SharePoint but not to an external URL for some reason.

Here's what I am using

```
SPUtility.Redirect(newURL, SPRedirectFlags.DoNotEncodeUrl|SPRedirectFlags.Trusted, HttpContext.Current);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `SPUtility.Redirect` for external URLs, use the regular `HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect` method.

Comment: I tried to use that also but it's also not transferring at all

Comment: Are you trying to redirect in an event receiver or something?

Answer (score 0):

I used the following and it worked (from a Webpart on a Page).

```
SPUtility.Redirect("http://www.cnn.com", SPRedirectFlags.DoNotEndResponse | SPRedirectFlags.Trusted, HttpContext.Current);
```

You could probably omit 'SPRedirectFlags.DoNotEndResponse'.